# How do I use HiltViewModelFactory in non-Android classes?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

How can one go about injecting HiltViewModelFactory into non-Android components like Conductor's Controller.. etc. Currently I have this code but it doesn't work, saying HiltViewModelFactory cannot be provided.

```kotlin
@EntryPoint
  @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
  interface MyClassInterface {
    fun viewModelFactory(): HiltViewModelFactory
  }

  private val viewModelStore = ViewModelStore()

  private val viewModelFactory by lazy {
    EntryPoints.get(requireContext(), MyClassInterface::class.java).viewModelFactory()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class HiltViewModelModule {
    @Provides fun viewModelFactory(activity: Activity): HiltViewModelProviderFactory = 
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory() as HiltViewModelFactory
}
```

This should work correctly in any Activity that is annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.

Comment: That doesn't work, it's posted as issue and it will be added later in future|
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1958#event-3493042320

Comment: Well, that's a bummer, tbh.